# Python отправить запрос на сервер и сразу же прервать

Tags: python, запрос, get

Всем привет, в распоряжении есть пайтон(чистый) возможности установить библиотеку нет. Ограничение по времени 1 с.
использую

```
 import requests
 requests.get(ссылка)
```

или

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen(ссылка)
```

превышает лимит времени, и на сервер ничего не приходит. Но с компа все работает, как отослать запрос и не ожидать ответа? прервать его? Есть мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: Попробуйте timeout установить, пример из requests http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts

Comment: @Andrey пробовал, не работает, не приходит запрос на сервер

Comment: Вам шашечки или ехать? Что в итоге надо делать, не ждать выполнения или прервать запрос? не ждать выполнения - https://habr.com/ru/post/149420/ . прервать запрос у вас и так работает. и поведение ожидаемо, запрос прерывается и не важно дошел он уже до сервера или нет.

Comment: а что вы получаете в результате выполнения ? `r = requests.get(ссылка,  timeout=0.05)`